# Inner automorphisms of $S_3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, permutations

> How do I prove that $S_3 \simeq \wp(S_3)$? So I must show that the group of inner automorphisms of $S_3$ is isomorphic to $S_3$.

I haven't been given many examples on how to do these types of questions but I know if someone can provide an explicit answer I will know how to do similar questions.

Comment: @user I did, it is in the second sentence. It is an inner automorphism.

Answer (score 2):

My goal is to prove that $S_3$ is isomorphic to the group of inner automorphisms of $S_3$. Well, we can define a map $\phi$: $S_3$ ---> $\gamma$, where $\phi$(a) ---> $\gamma$(a). Define $\gamma$ as an inner automorphism. $\gamma$: a--->$gag^{-1}$. Now, since Z($S_3$), the center of $S_3$, is trivial, we have that the kernel of $\phi$ is (1). Now, this implies that $\phi$ is injective, so, it must map to at least 6 elements. Also note that $\phi$ is a homomorphism: we have : $\phi$(a)$\phi$(b)= $gag^{-1}$$gbg^{-1}$ = $gabg^{-1}$ = $\phi$(ab). $\phi$ is surjective: let $\gamma$: a--->$gag^{-1}$ be some arbitrary inner automorphism of $S_3$. Then, $\gamma$ = $\phi$(a). Therefore,$\phi$ is an isomorphism between $S_3$ and the group of inner automorphisms of $S_3$

Side note: Since $\phi$ is a homomorphism it must preserve the order of elements. Therefore, every element of order 2, (of which there are three), must be mapped to an element of order 2. Note that this implies there are 6 possible mappings for each transposition in $S_3$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: You have a map $S_3\to S_6$ which sends $x$ to its associated inner automorphism. The image of this map is obviously surjective onto the inner automorphisms. What is its kernel?

Comment: The center of $S_3$ is trivial so the kernel is trivial?

Comment: @user104235 Mhmm. So, what does this tell you?

Comment: That is what I am having trouble with.

Comment: @user104235 You have a map onto the inner automorphisms, whose kernel is trivial. What is another name for a surjective map of groups with trivial kernel?

Comment: it will be injective?

Comment: @user104235 So, you have an injective, and surjective map $S_3\to\wp(S_3)$...

Comment: But this is what I cant see. I am looking towards a more explicit answer so I can see what is actually going on. For example, using $S_3 = \{ f:\{1,2,3\}\to \{1,2,3\}\}$ to actually show it.

Comment: @user104235 I'm not really sure how more explicit you could want. I've just shown you that the map $S_3\to\wp(S_3)$ by sending an element to its associated inner automorphism is an isomorphism...

Comment: By explicit, I mean that since there are $6$ inner automorphisms how can I verify that distinct elements of $S_3$ give distinct inner automorphisms and considering what each inner automorphism does to the elements. Since the inner automorphism has the form $p_g: x \to gxg^{-1}$ I want to compute what each $p_g$ does to the elements then I can see clearly what is going on.

Comment: @user104235 I mean, that basically amounts to showing that the center is trivial--almost literally. If you have done that by hand, you have done precisely what you wanted. If not, it's notationally simpler to check that $S_3$ is centerless.

Comment: How can I do by hand? Can you show me please, for example if $g = (1,2,3)$?

Comment: @user104235 You literally take $gh$ and $hg$ for all $h\in S_3$ and see if those two are equal. You can do that, can't you?

Comment: So if I let $h = (1,3,2)$ then I must see if $gh$ and $hg$ are equal?

Comment: @user104235 Yes, but you must do this for all $h$.

Comment: Okay then, I will do it.